# Search for SQL records and return the number of rows found with SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

Apologies if this has been posted but I've spent two days searching and found nothing.

I need to be able to search a SQL database, return the number of records found in a HTML/PHP form and scroll through the result set. Ideally I would like to do this by displaying links to each record so [1] [2] [3] etc. Is there a way to do that using SQLSRV?

Comment: What will be the content of your HTML table - the values from each record in MS SQL table, or just a link with the record number? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+pagination

Comment: I'm using a form so I guess I need the page to refresh on each selection of a record?